# Passing in select menu into nested form's attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, drop-down-menu, nested-forms, nested-attributes

I have a nested form that has a select dropdown menu.

**How can I pass the selected item's ID into the attributes that are submitted when the 'submit' button is hit?**

In my situation, this is what my nested form's partial looks like:

```
=select("dish", "menu_id", Menu.all.collect {|r| [ r.name, r.id ] }, {:include_blank => 'Choose a Menu'})  
=f.hidden_field :_destroy
=f.text_field :name, placeholder: "Name"
=f.text_field :price, placeholder: "Price"
=link_to "X", '#', :class => "remove_fields"
```

When I hit the submit button, the Terminal/Console displays that the following are being submitted to the database but you'll notice that the `menu_id` from the dropdown menu isn't part of the `dishes_attributes` since it doesn't share the same input `id` and `name` as the other two fields.

```
... "dishes_attributes"=>{"1342759486320"=>{"_destroy"=>"false", "name"=>"Dish 1", "price"=>"32"} ...
```

From the HTML source code, the `name` and `price` input fields get assigned the following `id` and `name`:

```
<input id="side_dish_dishes_attributes_1342759902918_name" name="side_dish[dishes_attributes][1342759902918][name]" placeholder="Name" size="30" type="text"/>
<input id="side_dish_dishes_attributes_1342759902918_price" name="side_dish[dishes_attributes][1342759902918][price]" placeholder="Price" size="30" type="text"/>
```

But my `select` dropdown looks like this:

```
<select id="dish_menu_id" name="dish[menu_id]">
  <option value="">Choose a Menu</option>
  <option value="1">Menu 1</option>
  <option value="2">Menu 2</option>
</select>
```

In the parent `_form` page, here's what the call looks like that then calls this partial:

```
=link_to_add_fields "Add New Dish", f, :dishes
```

With the `link_to_add_fields` looking like this from my `helpers/application_helper.rb`:

```
def link_to_add_fields(name, f, association)
  new_object = f.object.send(association).klass.new
  id = new_object.object_id
  fields = f.fields_for(association, new_object, child_index: id) do |builder|
    render(association.to_s.singularize + "_fields", f: builder)
  end
  link_to(name, '#', class: "add_fields", data: {id: id, fields: fields.gsub("\n", "")})
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of this line

```
=select("dish", "menu_id", Menu.all.collect {|r| [ r.name, r.id ] }, {:include_blank => 'Choose a Menu'})
```

use it with form object

```
=f.select("menu_id", Menu.all.collect {|r| [ r.name, r.id ] }, {:include_blank => 'Choose a Menu'})
```

I hope this will sort out your id problem as well as part of dishes attributes

Comment: Thank you so much. This works perfectly! I knew I needed to incorporate the `f` into the `select` but wasn't sure how. Thanks again!

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked for me ...message from the future =)